# Shuffling all lists of a common second elements

Tags: python, shuffle

I have this list of lists:

```
[[1, 0.007], [2, 0.007], [3, 0.007], [4, 0.007], [5, 0.01], [6, 0.01], [7, 0.01], [8, 0.01], [9, 0.02], [10, 0.02], [11, 0.02], [12, 0.02], [13, 0.13], [14, 0.13], [15, 0.13], [16, 0.13], [17, 0.28], [18, 0.28], [19, 0.28], [20, 0.28], [21, 4.0], [22, 4.0], [23, 4.0], [24, 4.0]]
```

Which I'd like to rearange so that all lists of a common second elements (0.007, 0.01, 0.02, 0.13, .28, 4) are randomly shuffled.

Like this, for instance:

```
[[3, 0.007], [1, 0.007], [4, 0.007], [2, 0.007], [7, 0.01], [6, 0.01], [5, 0.01], etc.
```

The first four lists (1,2,3,4), which all belong to a "0.007" series, are randomly shuffled together; the four next, all belonging to a "0.01" series are randomly shuffled, etc.

Comment: Define what you mean by "shuffled": why is the particular order in your example the correct one?

Comment: I tried to elaborate in the question. By shuffling, I mean "randomly mixing"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `itertools.groupby` and `random.shuffle` to reconstruct a randomized list of lists, like this:

```
In [23]: mix = [[1, 0.007], [2, 0.007], [3, 0.007], [4, 0.007], [5, 0.01], [6, 0.01], [7, 0.01], [8, 0.01], [9, 0.02], [10, 0.02], [11, 0.02], [12, 0.02], [13, 0.13], [14, 0.13], [15, 0.13], [16, 0.13], [17, 0.28], [18, 0.28], [19, 0.28], [20, 0.28], [21, 4.0], [22, 4.0], [23, 4.0], [24, 4.0]]

In [24]: from itertools import groupby

In [25]: import random

In [26]: groups = []

# grouping each list by 2nd item
In [27]: for _, g in groupby(mix, lambda x: x[1]):
   ....:     group = list(g)
   ....:     random.shuffle(group)  # then shuffle each list in place
   ....:     groups.extends(group)

In [28]: groups
Out[28]: 
[[2, 0.007], [4, 0.007], [3, 0.007], [1, 0.007],
 [8, 0.01], [5, 0.01], [7, 0.01], [6, 0.01],
 [11, 0.02], [9, 0.02], [10, 0.02], [12, 0.02],
 [15, 0.13], [13, 0.13], [14, 0.13], [16, 0.13],
 [20, 0.28], [19, 0.28], [17, 0.28], [18, 0.28],
 [21, 4.0], [22, 4.0], [24, 4.0], [23, 4.0]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from random import shuffle
a = [ key[0] for key in lists]
shuffle(a)
```

From here you can re-create the list with your static value[1] numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Just by simply  sorting on the 2nd element

```
def getkey(item):
    return item[1]

sorted(l,key=getkey)
```

Comment: I might understand your answer wrong, but this gives the same result every time. I need to have the list of lists sorted on the 2d element (like it already is), but then, I'd like each group of a common 2d element to be reshuffled randomly.

Comment: Ok, I see. What if you randomize the input list (http://smallbusiness.chron.com/randomize-list-python-26724.html) and then sort as above ? another way would consist in creating a list of lists (the inner list having the same 2nd element), and shuffle each of inner list.